# iOS14 history.back() cannot work 。history.length is always == 0

Tags: javascript, ios, ios14

My web app is working in a WKWebView of an iOS native application. There is a back button on the top-left side of the page, and it will go back to the previous page after the button is clicked. but recently many customers have upgraded their IOS to 14 now the back button cannot work.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout delay for a while when you use history.push. But I have not found way handle with Link tag.

```
setTimeout(() => {
       history.push('xxx');
 }, 100);
```